# Subsetting Images into Separate Folders in R

Tags: r

I have a folder with several thousand files inside. I want to subset all of these files into individual subfolders, each with 15 files (doesnt matter which files go where or subfolder names). Basically, I need to process these files in a program and I would like to break them down into folders with a smaller, more manageable number of files inside.

Comment: What OS are you using? You will probably have to use a scripting language to do that. Some scripts may be OS specific. Here's a OS agnostic solution for python: https://gist.github.com/zupo/5849843

Comment: I would like to use R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need several functions to do this.

`list.files`    to get all of the file names

`dir.create`    to create the directories   and

`file.rename`   to move the files

```
AllFiles = list.files("TheFolder")

## Make all of the folders
FolderNumber = floor(1:length(AllFiles)/15) + 1
FolderName = sprintf("Folder%03d", FolderNumber)
for(f in unique(FolderName)) { dir.create(f) }

## Move the files
for(i in 1:length(AllFiles)) {
    file.rename(paste("TheFolder", AllFiles[i], sep="/"),
        paste(FolderName[i], AllFiles[i], sep="/"))
}
```

If you want to be cautious,  you might use `file.copy` instead of `file.rename`. This will make a copy to the folders without deleting the original, so that you can check that everything is OK before deleting.

Comment: I am getting this error: Error in file.rename(paste("TheFolder", AllFiles[i], sep = "/"), paste(FolderName[i],  : 
  'from' and 'to' are of different lengths

Comment: Both from and to should have length 1. To see what is not working just type `i = 1`  then `paste("TheFolder", AllFiles[i], sep="/")` and `paste(FolderName[i], AllFiles[i], sep="/")`     Are both of these working?

Comment: yes, paste("TheFolder", AllFiles[i], sep="/") returns "TheFolder/NA" and paste(FolderName[i], AllFiles[i], sep="/") returns "Folder001/NA"

Comment: Just to be certain - You _did_ change "TheFolder" to be the name of your folder, right?

Comment: You just typed Allfiles, not AllFiles.  Is the f/F correct?

Comment: sorry, AllFiles. The F is correct. Same code as posted. Just changed the working directory and my folder name to TheFolder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172354/discussion-between-g5w-and-user1977802).